# Retrieve a cell value in a RadGrid using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, radgrid

Working on an application using vs2008, I retrieve the value of a cell, my code is as follows:

```
var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>");

var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView(); 

var row = MasterTable.get_dataItems()[eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical()];

var cell = MasterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "CategoryID");
```

It does not work, I think the problem comes with the instruction `$find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>")`

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you

Comment: I think you might want to add more description on "it does not work".  What is it you intend to happen?  What is it that actually happens?

Comment: show us the complete script. and what errors you're seeing in browser-console?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to tell with this amount of information, but as a guess, if your code can't find the grid itself then it might be a timing issue. A lot of the Telerik controls aren't ready until pageLoad, so give it a try in there and see if you at least get the grid object:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
    var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView(); 
    var row = MasterTable.get_dataItems()[eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical()];
    var cell = MasterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "CategoryID");
}
```